# How can I design a region settings like this in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

Till now I have a combo-box control which displays all the available region language in the UI as a combo-box items.

its in WPF and MVVM

```
<ComboBox
   x:Name="cbLanguage"
   Grid.Row="1" 
   Height="30"
   Width="200"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
   VerticalAlignment="Top"
   ItemsSource="{Binding LocalLanguages,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
   SelectedIndex="0">
```

But I saw this window and thought this looks much more legant and modern. 
[image]

[image]

Can I do similar kind of window in WPF.

I tried to change the Combobox with list-box, List-view but no result.

Any help if there is any control in WPF which can do this.

This solves many problem specially if the combo box have more than 10 items user has to scroll through the all and then select the last index. But in this way user can select any locals as all are displayed in the UI. Even user can have the option to display alphabetically.

Answer (score 2):

arraging items in 3 columns can be achieved by using `UniformGrid` as ItemsPanel

```
<ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate >
        <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
```

modify `ItemTemplate` to change items apperance and have green color for selected item

i think it is necessary to modify `ComboBox` template to have custom header and footer in a dropDown (`Edit Template`-`Edit a Copy` in Visual Studio designer)

Answer (score 1):

In WPF combobox is basically a `Popup` when the `toggle button` is pressed.

You could implement your own `popup` or you could have a look at the `template` of the `ComboBox`. Here is a link to [ComboBox template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)